# How to import selected columns and rows of excel file to listView c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'am using `listView` to import excel file because all of my table is `listView`.

How to import selected column and rows of excel file to `listView`? Because it's only working if I make a column in first row or "A1" and if possible can I use where query that will match to their NAMES or ID? Thank you for giving me a hand!

This is my example Excel file that will import to my listView.

[image: SAMPLE EXCEL]

**my code**

```
string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtFileName.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
DataTable table = new DataTable();
string excelName = "Sheet1";
string strConnection = string.Format(connStr);
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);
conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter oada = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + excelName + "$]", strConnection);

table.TableName = "TableInfo";
oada.Fill(table);
conn.Close();

// Clear the ListView control
listView1.Items.Clear();

// Display items in the ListView control
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow drow = table.Rows[i];

    // Only row that have not been deleted
    if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
    {
        // Define the list items
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["1ST"].ToString());

        // Add the list items to the ListView
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get all of the values from the first row, i.e. A1 -> [...]1 and create columns named with those values. Then add all of the rows.

Grab the first row, perhaps like:

```
foreach (Column c in ExcelColumns)
{
    listView.Columns.Add(c.Value);
}
```

**! Note this is not necessarily the correct code, just illustrative.**

...then have your code read

```
for (int i = 1; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
```

instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
```